# How to iterate elements of an integer arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I understand that when you iterate a regular array element it is like so:

```
int[] counter = new int[10];

for loop{
   counter[i] = 0;
}

when button clicked{
  counter[0]++; //For example
  counter[6]++;
}
```

However I'm not understanding how to iterate through elements of an arraylist. If someone could help me understand I'll be appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be [to use a for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
for(int elem : yourArrayList){
   elem;//do whatever with the element
}
```

Comment: "However I'm not understanding how to iterate through elements of an arraylist." I think OP said he understands how to use normal arrays but wondered how to iterate an ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

}
```

Or

```
Iterator<Object> it = arrayList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Object obj = it.next();
    //Do something with obj
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over an array list is really simple.

You can use either the good old `for loop` or can use the `enhanced for loop`

**Good Old for loop**

```
int len=arrayList.size();
for(int i = o ; i < len ; i++){
int a =arrayList.get(i);
}
```

**Enhanced for loop**

```
for(int a : arrayList){
//you can use the variable a as you wish.
}
```